# Cómo lanzar el evento beforeunload de un IFRAME desde el propio iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

Tengo una aplicación web (App-B) que está embebida dentro de un Iframe. Fuera del Iframe está la aplicaicón A (App-A)

De tal forma que:

```
App A--                      // domain of A: https.mydomain/mainApp
      |___ App B en Iframe   // IFRAME SRC="https.mydomain/iframeApp
```

**El problema es**: La Aplicación padre (App-A) tiene un menú de navegación con varias opciones. Al hacer un Click en una de esas opciones, la URL del navegador cambia y el IFRAME desaparece porque la App-A carga un contenido distinto (el IFRAME desaparece)

Al desaparecer el IFRAME, éste debería guardar automáticamente unos datos vía Ajax POST de un formulario

El document del Iframe contiene el siguiente código:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {

    // Lanzar una petición Ajax para grabar datos de un formulario
});
```

El problema es que el evento *beforeunload* nunca se dispara antes de que el Iframe desaparezca. He probado con *unload* y tampoco funciona.

La Pregunta es: Hay alguna forma de que el propio IFRAME ejecute un código antes de desaparecer del DOM? 
En principio no tengo acceso a añadir código a la aplicaqción padre (App-A)

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te aliento a que traduzcas tu pregunta antes que sea eliminada.

Comment: Welcome to SOes. This site is only for spanish speakers. If you want to get an answer here you will need to translate your question to spanish and then you will get the answer in spanish language too. Otherway you will have to post this question "as it is" in StackOverflow (english version). Have a nice day!

Comment: Traducido, perdón por la confusión del idioma

Comment: Por curiosidad: ¿por qué redactaste la pregunta en inglés? ¿Llegaste desde [so] o accediste directamente a [es.so]? Nos encontramos con este caso diariamente y nos sería muy útil saber el motivo de la confusión, para poder mostrar la información de manera más clara y explicitar que este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas en castellano.

Comment: Casi siempre que busco algo en Google y sale SO es en inglés.
Al buscar la URL de vuestra web en Google para logarme, debió salir la que tiene el dominio es.stackoverflow...No me di cuenta y redacté en inglés, ya que es el idioma que suelo utilizar para las cosas técnicas.